# Make submit of form slower

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jquery to make a form submit slower?

So for example when a user does a search it will do the loading 2-3 seconds longer for the postback?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's so I can demonstrate something that is currently posting back instantly

Comment: OK... Post some code perhaps and it will be clearer what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's just a normal HTML form. But when the user submits the form it will do the action straight away and postback the page. I want to make this slower. No delay but the actual process so I can demonstrate how the page loading works.

Comment: I have seen a number of situations like this and even implemented delay code like this simply to deal with user perception. I.e. when something happens too fast users think it didn't actually work. You have to slow down the process, via sleep or some animation, to make them believe that their keypress actually did some work.

Comment: Thanks Paul that is essentially what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you would need to do this, but you could do something like this:

```
var submitted = false;
$("form").bind('submit', function(){
    if(!submitted){
        submitted = true;
        setTimeout(function(){ $("form").trigger('submit');}, 3000);
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeh this works fine :) I'll accept as soon as Stack allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

var t = setTimeout(*"javascript statement"*,milliseconds);

That might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a server side request, you could always just delay the response. In PHP this could be done with [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php).

```
sleep(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    yourFormSubmitionAfter2Seconds();
}, 2000);
```

or in PHP

```
sleep(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a click method that does something (e.g. a delay) and than triggers the post if it's ready? Like so:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  //wait, demonstrate, whatever
  //post my form
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want this but you can possibly make your form submit programmatically and have.

```
$`('#form').delay(2000).submit();
```

`